Is there any handy way to distribute rust crates as apt/brew packages?
I am curious whether there is a way to make it possible to install a Rust crate using apt or brew?
If it is possible, what is the most convenient way to do so?
To clarify the details: I am building a project, that is a system application and I want to be able to download it from any unix/macOS machine.
